# How do I roast a marshmallow over lava in Iceland?

Tags: food-and-drink, iceland

The title is basically my question. I'll be going to Iceland in mid-February. I've got it in my head that I want to make a s'more, cooking over lava as a heating method, while I'm there and I'm looking for a way to get this done. 
(Also, and I don't know if that will put too much sulfur into the marshmallow and it will kill me. I know this isn't right place for that particular question, but if you know that I'll die from it, I'd appreciate the heads up :) )

Comment: This may also be a good fit for Outdoors.SE.

Comment: I'd say it is close enough to fit here, fitting in with several other Iceland questions we have.

Comment: Lava is very very hot. The heat is not closely confined to directly above the lava. You're going to need some kind of fireproof suit and very long pole to acheive this.

Comment: Please see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136724/45630

Comment: Not an answer to your exact question, but there is a restaurant in Lanzarote called El Diablo where they cook food over a volcano.

Comment: you may able to roast but not eat it....

Comment: I've roasted marshmallows over slag with a longish pole, but only after it had solidified a bit since it was too hot when liquid. I'm still alive.

Comment: [It's always Friday in Iceland](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21413/38765)

Comment: If you want to live dangerously, why don't you just try some Hákarl, a national dish of Iceland made of fermented shark.

Answer (score 9):

You can roast a marshmallow over a vent in the volcano Eldfell, which erupted over the town of Heimaey in the stunning Westman Islands in 1973. You can take a commercial ferry to the island. From there, it's a short drive to the base of the volcano, and you can walk/scramble up the pebbly side of the volcano to the curved summit over the caldera. You'll find a beautiful view and tourists roasting marshmallows over steaming vents.[image]
[image]